# How to run a program inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm running an application called [ERDDAP](http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/index.html) using [this Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/axiom/docker-erddap/) run thusly:

```
docker stop erddap
docker rm erddap
docker run -p 8090:8080 -p 8543:8443 -d -v /usr/local/erddap/tomcat-users.xml:/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml -v /usr/local/erddap:/opt/tomcat/content/erddap -v /usr/local/erddapData:/erddapData --name erddap axiom/docker-erddap
```

This application reads a `datasets.xml` file that is supposed to be generated by an application called `GenerateDatasetsXml` that is inside the container: 
http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/download/setupDatasetsXml.html#GenerateDatasetsXml

So how can I run this program that is inside the Docker container to generate my `datasets.xml` file?

Comment: Just adding the name of the executable at the end of your `docker run` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute shell commands inside your docker container run:

```
$ docker exec -it erddap bash
```

This will take you into the docker container at /opt/tomcat. Your command prompt will look like this

```
root@d2adcc7db35a:/opt/tomcat#
```

First verify that your erddapData folder is at /erddapData, then run:

```
cd /opt/tomcat/webapps/erddap/WEB-INF/
bash GenerateDatasetsXml.sh
```

This will start the GenerateDatasetsXml script. Once you have answered all the questions, you can get out of the container using:

```
exit
```

The output from this script is in your local erddapData directory:

```
$ cd /usr/local/erddapData/logs/
$ cat GenerateDatasetsXml.out
```

You can copy the output into the spot where you need it in your datasets.xml document, which you should save in /usr/local/erddap/

Comment: cool, I didn't know that you could exec a bash script inside the container