# How can I log into a running docker instance?

Tags: docker, hostname, amazon-ec2, aws

poking `docker` to see how it works:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo docker run --net=host -d -t jmar71n/freepbx
2792243260a8de33d1a775d115188e601fc556e500b5ad085e09b4133d0f3d06
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo docker run -it jmar71n/freepbx bash
root@46f45b8973c3:/# 
root@46f45b8973c3:/# exit
exit
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo docker run -it jmar71n/freepbx bash
root@813557bf8922:/# 
root@813557bf8922:/# echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
root@813557bf8922:/#
```

Now, is each `run` a new instance?  Is that why the prompt changes? The `hostname` is a unique ID for each `run`?

How would I login to the first instance, with `--net=host`?

When I try the [exec flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266853/17056), it fails:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo docker exec -it jmar71n/freepbx bash
Error: No such container: jmar71n/freepbx
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$
```

Why?  What's the correct way to login to that instance?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              20c44cd7596f        2 days ago          123MB
hello-world         latest              725dcfab7d63        2 weeks ago         1.84kB
jmar71n/freepbx     latest              8dda2a58fde1        19 months ago       1.54GB
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker run, creates a new instance ([para](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) virtualised) environment from a given image.

To log in to a given instance, you need to run docker exec but you need to execute docker exec with the id of the container you are looking to log into. This can be attained from the command:

```
docker ps -a
```

Then with the id attained, log into the container with:

```
docker exec -it <containerid> bash
```

Comment: the `<containerid>` is not running...tried a bunch.  ?

Comment: That then suggests an issue with the way the image has been built. There is probably an issue with the entry point.

Comment: While both can be used for isolating processes, paravirtualization and containers are two very different technologies.

Comment: ok, works fine.  not sure what the prob was last time.  thx.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute `run` command, you create new container each time.

You execute `run` with options `-it` so you are being connected inside docker container, that's why your prompt is changing. So, all commands you execute with a new prompt will be executed inside the container.

When you say `exit` you terminate your active process (bash since you pass it as a parameter during creation) and your container stops since it lives only as long as the main process with PID 1 lives.

In order to connect to the instance, first, run it with `-d` in detached mode and then you can run `docker attach`. [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) You can get an ID of your container by `docker ps -a`. Same with `docker exec -it <containerID> bash`.